# How to add quotes around words in python using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I have following json type string text

```
blockAddress:{strandId:"C1DYN7Cag8oDCRRoIJ1uAz",
sequenceNo:68794},
transactionId:"AYj8Vf4kQ9EE6BJJbvt3js",
blockTimestamp:2019-12-03T08:00:04.899000001Z,
blockHash:{{gdOVqf7AsgaQf90ZK1Hsva2lzPckHnxGmm3plDRBeGA=}},
entriesHash:{{n8oUjERAqT9kL+Cr59P6UPJbIdyPvaP0R9ey9+Njdzc=}}
```

I want to add quotes(" ") around a word which has [a-zA-Z] characters and ends with colon(:) symbol.

Then my above string need to look likes follows:

```
"blockAddress":{"strandId":"C1DYN7Cag8oDCRRoIJ1uAz",
"sequenceNo":68794},
"transactionId":"AYj8Vf4kQ9EE6BJJbvt3js",
"blockTimestamp":2019-12-03T08:00:04.899000001Z,
"blockHash":{{gdOVqf7AsgaQf90ZK1Hsva2lzPckHnxGmm3plDRBeGA=}},
"entriesHash":{{n8oUjERAqT9kL+Cr59P6UPJbIdyPvaP0R9ey9+Njdzc=}}
```

I am trying this `re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z]+:)', r'"\1"', s)`. But I am getting quotes after colon. Like

```
"blockAddress:"{"strandId:""C1DYN7Cag8oDCRRoIJ1uAz",
"sequenceNo:"68794},
"transactionId:""AYj8Vf4kQ9EE6BJJbvt3js",
"blockTimestamp:"2019-12-03T08:00:04.899000001Z,
"blockHash:"{{gdOVqf7AsgaQf90ZK1Hsva2lzPckHnxGmm3plDRBeGA=}},
"entriesHash:"{{n8oUjERAqT9kL+Cr59P6UPJbIdyPvaP0R9ey9+Njdzc=}}
```

What I need to change in above regex? or Is there any different approach in python?

Comment: Please only use the JSON tag or description for things that *actually comply with the JSON specification*. If it doesn't comply with the spec, it isn't actually JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yH0WEZ/1):

```
txt = '''blockAddress:{strandId:"C1DYN7Cag8oDCRRoIJ1uAz",
sequenceNo:68794},
transactionId:"AYj8Vf4kQ9EE6BJJbvt3js",
blockTimestamp:2019-12-03T08:00:04.899000001Z,
blockHash:{{gdOVqf7AsgaQf90ZK1Hsva2lzPckHnxGmm3plDRBeGA=}},
entriesHash:{{n8oUjERAqT9kL+Cr59P6UPJbIdyPvaP0R9ey9+Njdzc=}}'''

import re

print( re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z]+):', r'"\1":', txt) )
```

Prints:

```
"blockAddress":{"strandId":"C1DYN7Cag8oDCRRoIJ1uAz",
"sequenceNo":68794},
"transactionId":"AYj8Vf4kQ9EE6BJJbvt3js",
"blockTimestamp":2019-12-03T08:00:04.899000001Z,
"blockHash":{{gdOVqf7AsgaQf90ZK1Hsva2lzPckHnxGmm3plDRBeGA=}},
"entriesHash":{{n8oUjERAqT9kL+Cr59P6UPJbIdyPvaP0R9ey9+Njdzc=}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you want is:

```
re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z]+):', r'"\1":', s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a *lookahead assertion*:

```
re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z]+)(?=:)', r'"\1"', input)
```